# Is taking a Koszul complex of a function a functor?

Tags: category-theory

While reading about Koszul complexes in Bruns and Herzog,
  I came across the following proposition:

> Suppose $L$ and $L'$ are $R$-modules
>     with linear forms $f : L \to R$
>     and $f' : L' \to R$.
>   Every $R$-homomorphism $\phi : L \to L'$ extends to
>     a homomorphism $\bigwedge \phi : \bigwedge L \to \bigwedge L'$
>     of $R$-algebras,
>     as discussed above.
>   If $f = f' \circ \phi$,
>      then $\bigwedge \phi$
>      is a homomorphism of Koszul complexes:
>
> **Proposition 1.6.8**
>   With the notation just introduced,
>     if $f = f' \circ \phi$,
>     then $\bigwedge \phi : K_*(f) \to K_*(f')$
>     is a complex homomorphism.
>
> *-- Bruns, Winfried and Jurgen Herzog (2005). Cohen-Macaulay Rings.
>   Page 46. Section 1.6.*

My understanding of this proposition is that
  every $R$-module homomorphism $\phi : L \to L'$
  induces a map
  $$ \begin{array}{rcl}
    \phi : \text{Hom}(L',R) & \to & \text{Hom}(L,R) \\
    f' & \mapsto & f' \circ \phi.
  \end{array} $$
This in turn induces
  chain maps $\bigwedge \phi : K_*(f' \circ \phi) \to K_*(f')$,
  for every $R$-linear form $f' : L' \to R$.
For curiosity's sake,
  my question is whether I can do the following.
(Bear in mind that
  I do not even know if the categories will be well-defined,
  since I am not comfortable with category theory.)

**Attempted definition**
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the category of $R$-linear forms.
Its objects are $\text{Hom}(L,R)$,
  with morphisms $\phi$ as defined above,
  for each $R$-module homomorphism $\phi$.
Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the category
  of Koszul complexes $K_*(f)$.
Its objects are of the form
  $$
    K(L) := \{ K_*(f) : \text{Domain of $f$ is $L$.\} }
  $$
Its morphisms are the chain complexes
  between Koszul complexes.

**Question**
Is taking the Koszul complexes of $R$-module homomorphisms
  a (contravariant) functor $\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{K}$?

**Attempted proof**
By definition of Koszul complex, there is a map
  $$ \begin{array}{rcl}
    K_* : \mathcal{L} & \to & \mathcal{K} \\
      \text{Hom}(L,R) & \mapsto & K(L) \\
                    f & \mapsto & K_*(f),
  \end{array} $$
  defined by taking Koszul complexes.
The proposition from Bruns and Herzog
  then shows that every morphism $\phi \in \text{Mor}(\mathcal{L})$
  gives a morphism $\bigwedge \phi \in \text{Mor}(\mathcal{K})$.
It reverses the order of the objects in the morphism,
  so it is contravariant if it is a functor.
Identity is certainly preserved.
Composition is preserved as well:
  $$
    \bigwedge(\phi' \circ \phi)
    : K_*(f'' \circ \phi' \circ \phi)
      \xrightarrow{\bigwedge\phi}
      K_*(f'' \circ \phi')
      \xrightarrow{\bigwedge\phi'}
      K_*(f'').
  $$
This shows that $K_*$ is indeed a functor.